# PL SQL t9 oracle

Tags: sql

i want to recognise 1 thing. I want to solve task about T9 encription. I have table T9_encryiption with columns codes which are numbers from 1 to 9. and in second column letters. There is needed to enter a variable2:='YAGUBZADA' and the output should be 924829232 using T9_encryiption table records in for loop. I have example code but in this code the table and for loop  are not used .

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the `T9_ENCRYPTION` table in your function, then just output the result of that function.

```sql
DECLARE
    FUNCTION t9_encrypt (p_text VARCHAR2)
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        l_encrypted_text   VARCHAR2 (4000);
    BEGIN
        SELECT LISTAGG (t.codes) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY w.lvl)     AS encrypted_text
          INTO l_encrypted_text
          FROM (    SELECT SUBSTR (p_text, LEVEL, 1) AS single_char, LEVEL AS lvl
                      FROM dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (p_text)) w
                JOIN t9_encryption t ON (INSTR (t.names, w.single_char) > 0);

        RETURN l_encrypted_text;
    END;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(t9_encrypt('YAGUBZADA'));
END;
```

Comment: what about without function? is there any way to do it with for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with that data model and the assignment is to use a PL/SQL loop over the table, you could convert each `names` value to a regex pattern - for example changing `'A,B,C'` to `'(A|B|C)'` - and use that to replace those matching characters:

```
declare
  variable2 varchar2(100) := 'YAGUBZADA';
begin
  for r in (select codes, names from t9_encryiption) loop
    variable2 := regexp_replace(variable2, '(' || replace(r.names, ',', '|') || ')', r.codes);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(variable2);
end;
/

924829232
```

That assume the `names` value for `1` is a space, as in your string version; if it's null you could `coalesce` or `nvl` it, or exclude that row.

Or you could use a second loop to split each comma-separated list into individual characters and replace those individually:

```
declare
  variable2 varchar2(100) := 'YAGUBZADA';
begin
  for r1 in (select codes, names from t9_encryiption) loop
    for r2 in (
      select regexp_substr(r1.names, '[^,]+', 1, level) as name
      from dual
      connect by regexp_substr(r1.names, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
    )
    loop
      variable2 := replace(variable2, r2.name, r1.codes);
    end loop;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(variable2);
end;
/

924829232
```

which would work with a space or null for `1`.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7510b8dc462d5ae17f6649c1220630e9)

You can do it without PL/SQL too, e.g. by generating the translate arguments from the table:

```
select translate('YAGUBZADA',
  listagg(replace(names, ',')) within group (order by codes),
  listagg(rpad(codes, length(replace(names, ',')), codes)) within group (order by codes))
from t9_encryiption
```

You don't have to remove the commas but it seems neater to do so.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9964cffa3c8be642aa619d4376c1ec08)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes i understood what u explained. I had difficulties to apply all these to this problem.